My Solana Rpc Node gets behind syncing
I have bought a ovhcloud server and setup node here.
System specs are : 
CPU: 2× AMD Epyc 9354 - 32c/64t - 3.25 GHz/3.8 GHz 
RAM: 768 GB ECC 4800 MHz 
System: disks 2×960 GB SSD NVMe Soft RAID 
Data disks: 12×3.84 TB SSD NVMe Soft RAID 
Bandwidth: 6Gbps, Datacenter location: Canada
But until it finishes sync the full network, it works well, but after the sync, it starts to get behind, and it continuously gets behind syncing.
I need to get this done asap.
Please help. 
Thank you!

How far the block behind from your network and maine

@AnggaAndrean It is delayed and delayed every second.
